# ASP.NET MVC download prompt not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, download

I'm trying to generate a Excel .xlsx file in a controller action. I would like to have the website show a download prompt to download the resulting file. The controller actions executes fine, but no download prompt is shown. Nothing happens.

I've tried:

```
         MemoryStream mstream = ... //generated file;

         return File(mstream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", model.DisplayName + ".xlsx");
```

I've tried:

```
        return new FileStreamResult(mstream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = model.DisplayName + ".xlsx" };
```

I've tried:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + model.DisplayName + ".xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        Response.Write(mstream.ToArray());
        Response.End();

        return Content("");
```

I even tried saving the file to disk, then returning via the filepath

```
        return File(filepath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following code in an MVC project.

```
public ActionResult GetCSV()
{
    string filename = "example";
    string csv = MyHelper.GetCSVString();
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", string.Format("{0}.csv", filename));
}
```

My csv string could look something like this

```
"Col1,Col2,Col3\nRow1Val1,Row1Val2,Row1Val3\n"
```

To trigger this download in a new window I call the following JavaScript

```
window.open('/MyUrl/GetCSV', 'DownloadWindowName');
```

Comment: That last part 'triggering the download in a new window with javascript' actually did the trick. I've tried this with a couple of things I've shown above, and they work.

Comment: The JS - window.open prompted the downloading, BUT why it didn't happen when I called the same from $ajax .. url - 'controller','action' style ?

Comment: @Rigin I had the same issue, and I've just discovered that you can't do it through Ajax because JavaScript cannot save files directly to a user's computer because of security concerns. So now I call the Controller by opening a new window with the needed parameters.

Comment: Thanks for sharing info.. it should be helping someone coming here.

Comment: @Bjorn do you put that javascript call inside of a function? or inside of the document ready?

Comment: @New_Coder No Idea, I asked the original question in Feb 2015 :p

Answer (score 0):

Add the header as follows.

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName =  model.DisplayName + ".xlsx",
                Inline = false
            };
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

then return the file as follows

```
return File(mstream, ".xlsx");
```

Regarding download prompt. If you mean a prompt where it asks where to save the file, then it depends on how the user has set it up in their browser settings. For example in chrome, users can choose not to get a prompt when downloading files and have it downloaded to a pre specified location like the download folder.
http://malektips.com/google-chrome-prompt-download-file.html#.VM-DbFWsUm8

Comment: I'm afraid this does not show me a download prompt either. When I click the button on my page, the code is executed, breakpoints are hit. But it never starts downloading a file, or asks the user for a download location. Not in IE and neither in Chrome.

Comment: As I've mentioned, download prompt is not something you can force to show. If the user has set up their browser to automatically download stuff to a pre selected location it will download to that location automatically without prompting the user to select a location. I'm not sure why file download didn't happen. This is how I use it in all the pages where I have a file download. Though I haven't used it with a memory stream, it should work the same.